# HTML to PDF with Pandoc: How to change background color of the PDF?

Tags: xetex, pdf, pandoc, html

I want to change the background color of the default white to #353535 and for that I'm trying to use the 'backgroundcolor' variable like so,

```
pandoc FINAL.html \
> -f html \
> -V backgroundcolor:#353535 \
> -V linkcolor:teal \
> -V geometry:a4paper \
> -V geometry:margin=1cm \
> -V mainfont="Noto Sans" \
> --pdf-engine=xelatex \
> -o FINAL.pdf
```

But this isn't working and the PDF just defaults to white. I've tried changing the background-color through HTML but to no avail. Opening the HTML file in my browser results in exactly what I need but with wrong geometry. The geometry isn't an issue with pandoc, it's just that I can't figure out the PDF background thing.

PS. I only have basic knowledge of Pandoc, so please guide me through :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `header-includes.yaml`:

```yaml
---
header-includes: |
    \definecolor{bg}{HTML}{353535}
    \pagecolor{bg}
...
```

and call `pandoc` like this:

```bash
pandoc header-includes.yaml FINAL.html \
 -f html \
 -V linkcolor:teal \
 -V geometry:a4paper \
 -V geometry:margin=1cm \
 -V mainfont="Noto Sans" \
 --pdf-engine=xelatex \
 -o FINAL.pdf
```